# The meaning of "paros"

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, france, définition

I want to know the meaning of Paros in general and in this sentence too "Je calcule pas, ça les rends paros" it's a sentence from the French song "rodéo" Eva & Kidaki
Thanks

Comment: To be honest, even as a native myself find these lyrics not so easy to understand. I really hope I'll never live in a world where everybody speaks like that...

Comment: Thanks for you all 

Comment: @LaurentS. Not being easy to understand is precisely the goal. Slang purpose has always been a way for groups of people to communicate between each other without being understood by the outsiders. When a slang word/expression goes mainstream, a new one is adopted...

Answer (score 1):

*[Paro](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/paro)* is slang for "crazy / mad / paranoid".

> I take nothing into account, it drives them crazy.

Comment: Thanks  but can I ask you another question in the same song  .... the meaning of rider, I know it means plisser or to practice the activities at skating but I can't get the meaning in this sentence "je ride, ride, je fais du rodéo"