# Quel est l'origine du mot d'argot « paro » ?

Tags: argot, origine-ou-raison

Quel est l'origine du mot d'argot [*paro*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/paro#Fran%C3%A7ais), discuté dans une [autre question,](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/44194/25619) et comment est-il formé, s'agit-il de la troncation d'un nom (et si oui, lequel) ?

Answer (score 2):

L'origine géographique ne fait pas de doute, ce sont les Antilles françaises où ce mot désigne les personnes dépendantes à la drogue, spécialement le crack.

Voici une bonne définition trouvé dans un commentaire de 2016 sur [le dico des mots](https://dico-des-mots.com/definitions/paro.html):

> Aux Antilles, d’où est originaire [Kery James](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kery_James) (<s>Haïti</s>), un paro c’est un crackhead, clochard, qui demande de l’argent toute la journée pour acheter son caillou. Il paraît fou, il fait peur aux gens dans la rue, et il peut être passablement lourd.

Une [émission de France Culture](https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/sur-les-docks/martinique-et-guadeloupe-33-en-guadeloupe-du-crack-et-des-hommes), 2012, sur une association d'aide à ces paros.

> Près de trente ans après son apparition en Guadeloupe, le crack, dérivé de la cocaïne, circule librement, se consomme et continue de faire des ravages en Guadeloupe. Ceux qu'il aliène sont communément appelés "diables" ou "paro". Certains d'entre eux évoluent dans la rue et mènent une vie d'errants.

[Le Monde](https://www.lemonde.fr/societe/article/2009/03/07/en-guadeloupe-trois-femmes-doubout_1164905_3224.html), 2009 :

> Elle rit tout le temps, Myriam. Elle n'est pas une "paro" : "Paro, c'est quand tu es sale, que tu as passé toutes les barrières, que tu ne peux plus remonter la pente", explique-t-elle en désignant un type efflanqué en survêtement rouge, qui traîne, le regard vide. Il y en a pas mal à Pointe-à-Pitre.

Quant à l'étymologie, on ne peut faire que des conjectures. En voici trois :

> paranoïaque → parano → paro

> Espagnol *(en) paro (forzoso)* : chômeur.

> Paria ( Personne méprisée, mise au ban de la collectivité.) →  paro

La première, *parano*, est la plus vraisemblable. Elle rapportée dans un [autre article du Monde](https://www.lemonde.fr/archives/article/2004/03/02/leila-cassubie-l-ancienne-independantiste-dans-la-rue-avec-les-desherites_355142_1819218.html), daté de 2004:

> "Laïla" prend le temps d'aller écouter les SDF, les séropositifs rejetés du milieu familial et les "paros" (surnom donné aux drogués, diminutif de paranoïaques)

Comment: Merci ! C'est vraiment étonnant la dichotomie entre l'emploi dans les exemples et l'emploi dans la chanson _Je calcule pas, ça les rends paros_, vraiment plus aligné sur ta première piste étymologique, l'adjectif. Avec l'espagnol ça me donne l'impression qu'on est un peu au croisement d'abbréviations qui deviennent d'homonymes...